# Как сделать чтобы персонаж поворачивался и шёл за джойстиком? [Unity]

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

Я знаю что подобный вопрос уже задавали, но там так и не объяснили как это сделать.
[image: 1]

Мне нужно чтобы персонаж поворачивался и шёл за джойстиком.
Данный код работает немного не правильно.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FirstPersonMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Joystick joystick;
    public float speed = 5;
    Vector2 velocity;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        velocity.y = joystick.Vertical * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        velocity.x = joystick.Horizontal * speed * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.Translate(velocity.x, 0, velocity.y);
    }
}
```

[image: 2]

Спасибо за любую помощь и ответ ❤

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем чтобы персонаж шёл и поворачивался за джойстиком. Нужно поставить компонент "Character Controller" на персонажа, и написать этот код:

```
public Joystick joystick;
public float speed = 5;
Vector3 velocity;
private CharacterController ch_controller;

private void Start()
{
ch_controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
transform.LookAt(Vector3.forward * joystick.Vertical * 200 + Vector3.right * joystick.Horizontal * 200);
velocity = Vector3.zero;
velocity.x = -joystick.Vertical * speed;
velocity.z = joystick.Horizontal * speed;
ch_controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
}
```